# JHipster, nothing is showing up

Tags: eclipse, jhipster

When I go to localhost:8080 after running the app, the webpage is completely empty. I only see the favicon.

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRREt1KB4Y8) tutorial, which just helps you setup a JHipster project.

I imported the project into Eclipse, following [these](http://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/) instructions.

I ran the app using Run As > Spring Boot App and also tried Run As > Run On Server. Even ran the mvnw file from the command line. The server starts fine, accessing the page gives me no error, but I don't see the JHipster home page thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run **both** `mvnw` for spring boot and `yarn start` for angular/webpack in development. Please check the docs: http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular